# Looping through an array embedded in stdClass

Tags: php, arrays, api, loops, stdclass

Using an API from our provider, I am getting the following data back from an API call:

Data (represents an orderid (1604) and then the individual items within the order):

```
object(stdClass)#395 (1) {  
    ["GetOrderDetailsInfoResult"]=> object(stdClass)#396 (4) {  
        ["RequestID"]=> int(113724)  
        ["Success"]=> int(1)  
        ["Message"]=> string(0) ""  
        ["OrderDetailsResponse"]=> object(stdClass)#397 (1) {  
            ["OrderDetailsResponse"]=> array(2) {  
                [0]=> object(stdClass)#53 (12) {  
                    ["OrderID"]=> int(1604)  
                    ["PartyID"]=> int(0)  
                    ["OrderDetailID"]=> int(805)  
                    ["ProductID"]=> string(3) "B25"  
                    ["Description"]=> string(16) "50 Credits"  
                    ["Quantity"]=> int(1)  
                    ["Price"]=> string(7) "25.0000"  
                    ["Volume"]=> string(7) "25.0000"  
                    ["Tax"]=> string(6) "0.0000"  
                    ["TaxableAmount"]=> string(6) "0.0000"  
                    ["GroupOwner"]=> int(0)  
                    ["ParentOrderDetailID"]=> int(0)  
                }  
                [1]=> object(stdClass)#419 (12) {  
                    ["OrderID"]=> int(1604)  
                    ["PartyID"]=> int(0)  
                    ["OrderDetailID"]=> int(807)  
                    ["ProductID"]=> string(4) "B100"  
                    ["Description"]=> string(17) "200 Credits"  
                    ["Quantity"]=> int(1)  
                    ["Price"]=> string(8) "100.0000"  
                    ["Volume"]=> string(8) "100.0000"  
                    ["Tax"]=> string(6) "0.0000"  
                    ["TaxableAmount"]=> string(6) "0.0000"  
                    ["GroupOwner"]=> int(0)  
                    ["ParentOrderDetailID"]=> int(0)  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

I can get as far as the RequestID, but I can't get into the values for the order...  How do I use php to get directly at the individual items?

Thanks.

Comment: Show your codes...why cant u get??

Comment: Could you re-enter the object with readable indentation, like var_dump() does?

Answer (score 0):

The items could be iterated over like this:

```
foreach($data->GetOrderDetailsInfoResult->OrderDetailsResponse->OrderDetailsResponse as $item)
{
    echo $item->ProductID;
    echo $item->Description;
    echo $item->Quantity;
    echo $item->Price;
}
```